# Is it possible for function to make a naked return on error in Golang?

Tags: go

I have a set of constructs like this:

```
func LoginUser(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // do some check here 
    if err != nil {
        ReturnErrorResponse(w, errors.LoginError)
        return
    }

    // do some check here 
    if err != nil {
        ReturnErrorResponse(w, errors.BannedUserError)
        return
    }

    //success
}
```

I wonder if it's possible to get rid of these `return`s and somehow embed them into the `ReturnErrorResponse` function?

So, if an error happens, I return a JSONified response with error code and make a naked return.

Comment: If you need to conditionally execute the success path, then you either need to return early (the idiomatic approach) or you need to put that code in a another conditional block.

Comment: A simple "No" is too short for SO but would be the right answer: No.

Comment: I do not understand the reason of downvoting

Comment: Usually, if users find the question helpful, sooner or later it gets some upvotes that balance initial downvotes so that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible by calling `panic()` e.g. in your `ReturnErrorResponse()` function (after sending back the error), but it's neither idiomatic nor efficient.

Using `panic()` would of course require to call `recover()` in a deferred function, which could be done in one place, e.g. in a "master" handler passed to [`http.ListenAndServe()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe).

What you're doing is the proper way. Do not use `panic()` for this.

Comment: I think I'd better just leave these `return`s as they are now, just need to get used to them, thanks!